# editable QComboBox InsertPolicy=QComboBox.AtTop doesn't insert new text

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

i tried to implement a editable QComboBox. But if you write a new item in the QLineEdit of the editable QComboBox this element does not appear in the list of QComboBox.

Must i insert the new text additionally by code?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import \
    QWidget, QComboBox, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton


class MyEditableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, insert_at=QComboBox.InsertAtTop):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setEditable(True)
        # we wanna some new data

        self.setInsertPolicy(insert_at)
        # the new text should be inserted


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        lyt = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(lyt)

        items = ["Burger",
                 "Chicken Wings",
                 "Pizza",
                 "Toast"]

        self.cbo = MyEditableComboBox(self)
        self.cbo.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.cbo.addItems(items)
        lyt.addWidget(self.cbo)

        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("Show Content of cbo")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._show_content_of_cbo)
        lyt.addWidget(self.btn)

    def _show_content_of_cbo(self):
        print("=" * 70)
        cbo = self.cbo
        for i in range(cbo.count()):
            print("{}: {}".format(i, cbo.itemText(i)))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you insert a "Steak" in the QLineEdit of the editable and then clicking on the button i saw the output:

```
======================================================================
0: Burger
1: Chicken Wings
2: Pizza
3: Toast
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: After typing "Steak" press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Documentation seems unclear when an item is added or not. It is not enough that you write for it to be added, but the QComboBox uses the returnPressed signal of the QLineEdit to add the item. So the solution is to execute some action that emits that signal like pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Comment: Ok i checked that out - but for me it seems as bad and unconvinient behaviour... I try to implement an insertion on the fly ... - thanks

Comment: @jgsedi mmm, at which events do you want the item to be inserted?

Comment: i want the new value to be inserted after leaving the widget - i think i will use the "focusOutEvent".

Comment: @jgsedi then create an event filter that detects this event, and at that moment get the text from the QLineEdit and add it to the QComboBox.

Comment: what do you mean by "event filter"? i thought to implement the "focusOutEvent" in the "MyEditableComboBox" class and there i must check the current text. if that text isnt in the list - so add it. Big lists could be problematic ...

Comment: @jgsedi Do you want to detect the focusOutEvent of the QLineEdit or the QComboBox?

Comment: the focusOutEvent of the QCombo!

Comment: @jgsedi ok, then it is enough to override method focusOutEvent